# Selenium Multiple File Upload + Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using below code for a multiple image upload :

```
import selenium
import time
import selenium.common.exceptions
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.alert import Alert
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

#provie file path for Chromedriver
chromedriver = "C:/Users/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get("https://url.com")

#log in to the website
driver.find_element_by_id('ctrlLogin_UserName').send_keys("xyz.com")
driver.find_element_by_id('ctrlLogin_Password').send_keys("abc@01")
driver.find_element_by_id('ctrlLogin_LoginButton').click()

#give some time for all objects to load
time.sleep(5)
driver.maximize_window()

#click open Reports tab
driver.find_element_by_xpath('full XPath').click()

#navigate to New Reports
driver.switch_to.frame("hostFrame")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('full XPath').click()

#give some time for all Reports to load
time.sleep(5)
driver.switch_to.default_content()

#Open Report folder
time.sleep(5)
driver.switch_to.frame("hostFrame")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('full XPath').click()

time.sleep(5)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 600);")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('full XPath').click()

time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('full XPath').click()

uploader = driver.find_element_by_xpath('full XPath')
uploader.send_keys("C:/Users/blabla.jpg")
```

I am getting an error as :
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
(Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.88)

I tried adding wait but that also did not work. Can someone share any ideas?

Comment: Provide the HTML code of the element in the post itself. Do not add the screenshot of html code, No one will write that for you.

Answer (score 0):

The element cannot be interacted with either because it is not visible or another element is displaying over it.
Double check it is in a state you can interact with it and visible and that you have the correct locator for it.
try to change

```
uploader.send_keys("C:\\Users\\blabla.jpg")
```

and :

```
scro=driver.find_element_by_xpath('full XPath')
scro.location_once_scrolled_into_view
scro.click()
```